# Valgrind indentation (and below main)

Tags: c, malloc, free, valgrind

Here is the valgrind output from a project:

```
==2433== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==2433==    at 0x402B06C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2433==    by 0x43F345B: av_freep (mem.c:172)
==2433==    by 0x5A6F4D2: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
==2433==  Address 0xb3fd830 is 48 bytes inside a block of size 111,634 alloc'd
==2433==    at 0x402BE68: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2433==    by 0x80BB6B5: _talloc_realloc (talloc.c:997)
```

The line starting with `Address` is indented by one space more compared to the line starting with `Invalid`. Does that mean one leads onto another? Or are they seperate?

If the are seperate, where does the `by 0x5A6F4D2: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)` come from? I get the feeling `(below main)` has something to do with it, but I can't find libc-start.c anywhere on my hard drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is providing you with additional details on the invalid free. The first four lines describe the invalid call (free in this case) and the call stack at the time of the free. The following three lines provide additional data. In this case, valgrind recognizes that the address passed to `free` is contained within an allocated region, and it provides the offset, size of the block, and call stack of that allocation.

Answer (score 1):

According to [valgrind.org](http://valgrind.org/gallery/linux_mag.html), the hierarchy should be flat, as shown below:

```
==3016== Invalid write of size 1
==3016==    at 0x80484DA: main (in /jfs/article/sample2)
==3016==    by 0x40271507: __libc_start_main (../sysdeps/generic/libc-start.c:129)
==3016==    by 0x80483B1: free@@GLIBC_2.0 (in /jfs/article/sample2)
==3016==    Address 0x40CA0224 is 0 bytes after a block of size 512 alloc'd
==3016==    at 0x400483E4: malloc (vg_clientfuncs.c:100)
==3016==    by 0x80484AA: main (in /jfs/article/sample2)
==3016==    by 0x40271507: __libc_start_main (../sysdeps/generic/libc-start.c:129)
==3016==    by 0x80483B1: free@@GLIBC_2.0 (in /jfs/article/sample2)
```

I would treat the indentation of `Address` in your output as the above, as it may be a version-specific change to make the output more readable.